# How to send content type in a request while doing parsing using Alamofire networking in Swift?

Tags: swift, parsing, afnetworking, alamofire, graphql

I am new to Swift. I want to parse a graphql webservice where i need to send the content type to header as "application/graphql". In general in Objective-C if we are using AFNetworking we can set up the content type as below.

```
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

In Swift i am using Alamofire, i don't have any idea regarding this, that how to set the content type. Being a new comer for Swift, please advised me without hesitation.

One more thing is graphql service don't accept a proper JSON, Please refer [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/01/graphql-introduction.html)

Please suggest me how to post the values to server? by preparing a string is only an answer? (Sorry if i misunderstood graphql). But please don't hesitate. Give your valuable suggestions.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass content type in header with the Alamofire you can try the following code.

```
// Step : 1  
    var manager = Manager.sharedInstance

    // Specifying the Headers we need
    manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
        "Accept": "application/json" //Optional
        ]

   // Step : 3 then call the Alamofire request method.

 Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON { request, response,  result in
     print(result.value)
  }
```